# Better way to import large csv or xlsx file and combine?

Tags: excel, pandas, csv, concatenation

I want to combine 5 years of H1B visa data with the below code in jupyter notebook.
5 files(H1B_16 to H1b_20) have more than 60k rows, 200mb each.

However, when trying to run the code, my system goes frozen. Not sure why, but it might be because those files are too big.

Would there be any better way to combine them to be used in Pandas dataframe?

```
# listing file name

filenames = []
for i in range(16,21):
    f = ("H1B_"+str(i)+".csv")
    filenames.append(f)   
print(filenames)


# listing columns needed

features = '''CASE_STATUS,DECISION_DATE,VISA_CLASS,JOB_TITLE,SOC_CODE,SOC_TITLE,EMPLOYER_NAME,WORKSITE_CITY,WORKSITE_COUNTY,WORKSITE_STATE,WORKSITE_POSTAL_CODE,WAGE_RATE_OF_PAY_FROM,WAGE_UNIT_OF_PAY,PREVAILING_WAGE,PW_UNIT_OF_PAY'''
features = features.split(',')
print(features)


# selecting columns in CSV file

def h1b_col(name):
    s = pd.read_csv(name)
    s = s[features]
    return s


# concatenate files in the list

combined_csv = pd.concat([h1b_col(f) for f in filenames ] )
combined_csv.to_csv("H1B_16_to_20.csv") 
combined_csv
```

Comment: Have you verified that you can import each file by itself using the code above?

Comment: @Brennan Yup. it can be imported but become frozen when do it all at once